# MSBuild NullReferenceException in Microsoft.TeamTest.targets

Tags: c#, msbuild, windows-server-2008-r2

On TFS 2010 I configured some CI builds that run MSTest unit tests too. This works fine, except for one solution, where I *usually* (but not always) get the following *build* (not test runner) error:

> C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\TeamTest\Microsoft.TeamTest.targets
>   (14): Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

The `Logging Verbosity` of the Build Definition is set to `Diagnostic`. [Some social.msdn.com posts](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/tfsbuild/thread/bb0a1752-f6ce-4001-8b45-5aa72f1909e3) suggest this to get rid of this very occasional error. If it were occasional, by the way, we could work around it by scheduling another build if it is broken for the above reason. It's not, however, and takes pretty much time to build too.

Even though it is a build error, it can be fixed by setting `Disable Tests` to `True`. I do want to run the test, however. Does anybody know how to fix this? The other (working) solutions are often subsets of `All Projects`'s projects. `All Project` is a rather big solution.

I have the shortened MSBuild Output here, in case it helps:

```
Run MSBuild for Project
Initial Property Values
AdditionalVCOverrides =
CommandLineArguments = /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true
Configuration = Release
GenerateVSPropsFile = True
LogFile =
LogFileDropLocation =
MaxProcesses = 1
OutDir = All Projects-CI\Binaries\Release
Platform = Any CPU
Project = All Projects-CI\Sources\Shared\All Projects.sln
ResponseFile =
RunCodeAnalysis = AsConfigured
Targets =
TargetsNotLogged = String[] Array
ToolPath =
ToolPlatform = Auto
Verbosity = Diagnostic
Built $/.../DataAccessLayer.Testing.csproj for default targets.

C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\TeamTest\Microsoft.TeamTest.targets (14): Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Comment: Have you got Private Accessors in the solution you mentioned? Everything seems to imply this error message relates to accessing private accessors, so if they aren't needed you could remove them. Or perhaps try regenerating them http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184796%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

That BuildShadowTask custom task in MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\TeamTest\Microsoft.TeamTest.targets is causing the error.  The reason why you don't see the error when you disable tests this build task doesn't run when tests are disabled.

Suggest adding MsBuild Message tasks to output the various values to determine which one is causing the "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" error.

Before this line:

```
  <BuildShadowTask
        ExecuteAsTool="False"
        CurrentResolvedReferences="@(ReferencePath)"
        CurrentCopyLocalFiles="@(ReferenceCopyLocalPaths)"
        Shadows="@(Shadow)"
        ProjectPath="$(ProjectDir)"
        IntermediatePath="$(IntermediateOutputPath)"
        SignAssembly="$(SignAssembly)"
        KeyFile="$(AssemblyOriginatorKeyFile)"
        DelaySign="$(DelaySign)">
```

Add a Message task to output the values of each parameter passed to the BuildShadowTask to determine which one is in error:

```
  <Message Text="AssemblyOriginatorKeyFile $(AssemblyOriginatorKeyFile)" Importance="High" />
```